# numpy: сумма случайной строки матрицы равна 1

Tags: python, numpy

Я генерирую рандомный массив float-чисел от 0 до 1 с шагом 0.01 и размерностью матрицы 7 на 14. С этим у меня проблем не возникло и по коду ниже все работает.

Но я не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы сумму строки из матрицы была равна ровно 1 и не более. Кто может подсказать как это сделать ?

```
random_float_array = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 1+0.5*0.01, 0.01), size=(7,14))
print('Matrix A\n',np.round(random_float_array,2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так разделите каждую из строк на сумму её элементов. Как-то так вроде:

```
random_float_array / random_float_array.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, а то у меня сейчас идея была сделать бесконечный цикл и там поставить условия про сумму и уже ждать пока оно высчитает 1. Но уже как 5 минут считает в колабе

Comment: @JuniorLittle Ну, это можно до тепловой смерти вселенной ждать, пока такое само выпадет. Особенно если пытаться сумму чисел с плавающей точкой сравнивать в точности с конкретным числом. )